# Vue3: how to factor out a `watch` statement in composition API

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have the following chunk of code that's duplicated across multiple components:

```js
    const mint = ref<string>('');
    watch(() => payload.mintPk, async (newVal) => {
      if (newVal.length >= 32) {
        mint.value = await prettifyMint(payload.mintPk);
      }
    });
    prettifyMint(payload.mintPk)
      .then((m) => {
        mint.value = m;
      });
```

I can't figure out how to factor it out into a standalone function that can be re-used across components. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mixin to reuse the code in multiple components.

The official documentation for mixins is here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html